# Concatenate column A data into column C using column B data

Tags: excel, formula

[image]

Using `if` condition I need column A data to be concatenated according to column b. See column C for results.

Answer (score 1):

Easy with a helper column.  In **D2** enter **1** and in **D3** enter:

```
=IF(B3="","",ROW())
```

and copy downwards.  In **C2** enter:

```
=IF(B2="","",TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,INDEX($A$2:A2,MAX($D$1:D1)):A2))
```

and copy downwards:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This needs 3 columns:

Into column C, type:

```
=COUNTIF($B10:$B$10,">0")
```

at the **bottom** of the column, and drag upwards. This counts the numbers in the range, and assigns each subrange a value.

Into column D, type:

```
=IF(C2<>C1,A2,CONCAT(D1," ",A2))
```

at the **top** of the column, and drag down. This concatenates each subrange.

Finally, into column E, type:

```
=IF(B2="","",D2)
```

at the **top** of the column, and drag down. This only shows the results we want.

Also, make sure there is a header or blank line at the start of the data.

[image: concatenation]

Comment: Thank you...it is working...but I am looking for this to get the result with one formula